# Is there eslint rule to prevent multiple calls of the same function to read values?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Let's say I have a method which returns some object:

```js
function getValue() {
  return {
    name: { ... },
    id: { ... },
    created: { ... },
  }
}
```

so the following code:

```js
const { name, id } = getValue()

console.log(name, id)

const { id, created } = getValue()

console.log(id, created)
```

can be easily converted to:

```js
const { name, id, created } = getValue()

console.log(name, id)

console.log(id, created)
```

There are might be exceptions when value might update between the calls when it will make sense to do separate calls but in general it is otherwise. Is there any eslint rule which would help to detect such cases?